# Exclude row based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to exclude rows where all gross columns have blank values.

Sample data:

```
market   item_id    gross_1     gross_2   gross_3   period
POLAND   1111       1           2         3         20190301
ESTONIA  2222       blank       2         3         20190302
POLAND   3333       1           blank     3         20190303
POLAND   3333       1           blank     blank     20190304
POLAND   4444       blank       blank     blank     20190305
POLAND   5555       1           2         3         20190306`
```

I'd like to receive:

```
market   item_id    gross_1     gross_2   gross_3   period
POLAND   1111       1           2         3         20190301
ESTONIA  2222       blank       2         3         20190302
POLAND   3333       1           blank     3         20190303
POLAND   3333       1           blank     blank     20190304
POLAND   5555       1           2         3         20190306`
```

I've found something like this, but it doesn't work in snowflake:

```
WHERE NOT ROW(gross_1, gross_2, gross_3) IS NULL
```

Comment: What does "blank" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/coalesce.html):

```
select * from tablename
where coalesce(gross_1, gross_2, gross_3) is not null
```

Comment: Elegant, if he means `NULL`. +1 Wrapping each element in a `NULLIF` for an empty string or the string 'blank' would work with the `COALESCE`, too. Nice one.

Comment: All 3 columns contain integers so I guess it's about nulls.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what "blank" means.  As shown in the data:

```
select t.*
from t
where not (gross_1 = 'blank' and gross_2 = 'blank' and gross_3  = 'blank')
```

If "blank" means empty string, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where not (gross_1 = '' and gross_2 = '' and gross_3 = '')
```

If it means `NULL`, then:

```
select t.*
from t
where not (gross_1 is null and gross_2 is null and gross_3 is null)
```

All these can be rephrased with `or`:

```
select t.*
from t
where gross_1 is not null or gross_2 is not null or gross_3 is not null
```

Comment: He wants to exclude them rather than include them, but yeah, this is how it's done.

Comment: @dvo . . . I left out the `not`.